# Inductive predicates, transitive closure, and code generation

Tags: isabelle

I am defining subclass and subtype relations as inductive predicates for a Java-like language and would like to generate code for these relations. Defining and generating code for the subtype relation was no problem:

```
type_synonym class_name = string

record class_def =
  cname :: class_name
  super :: "class_name option"
  interfaces :: "class_name list"

type_synonym program = "class_def list"

(* Look up a class by its name *)
definition lookup_class :: "program ⇒ class_name ⇒ class_def option" where
  "lookup_class P C ≡ find (λcl. (class_def.cname cl) = C) P"

(* Direct subclass relation *)
inductive is_subclass1 :: "program ⇒ class_name ⇒ class_name ⇒ bool" where
  "⟦
    Some cl = lookup_class P C;
    (class_def.super cl) = Some C'
  ⟧ ⟹ is_subclass1 P C C'"

(* Reflexive transitive closure of `is_subclass1` *)
definition is_subclass :: "program ⇒ class_name ⇒ class_name ⇒ bool" where
  "is_subclass P C C' ≡ (is_subclass1 P)⇧*⇧* C C'"


code_pred(modes: i ⇒ i ⇒ i ⇒ bool, i ⇒ i ⇒ o ⇒ bool) is_subclass1 .

code_pred
  (modes: i ⇒ i ⇒ i ⇒ bool, i ⇒ i ⇒ o ⇒ bool)
  [inductify]
  is_subclass .
```

Here, `is_subclass1 P C C'` is true if `C'` is the name of the direct superclass of `C`. Then `is_subclass` is defined to be the transitive closure of `is_subclass1`.

For code generation to work, it is crucial that `is_subclass1` has the mode `i ⇒ i ⇒ o ⇒ bool`, because otherwise the transitive closure cannot be computed. In the case of `is_subclass1` this is easy, as a class has at most a single direct superclass, and the name of the superclass can thus be uniquely determined from the inputs.

However, for the subtype relation I also need to consider the interfaces that a class might implement:

```
inductive is_subtype1 :: "program ⇒ class_name ⇒ class_name ⇒ bool" for P :: program where
  ― ‹Same as subclass relation, no problem›
  "⟦
    Ok cl = lookup_class P C;
    Some C' = (class_def.super cl)
  ⟧ ⟹ is_subtype1 P C C'" |

  "⟦
    Ok cl = lookup_class P C;
    ― ‹HERE IS THE PROBLEM: C' cannot be uniquely derived from the inputs and can thus not be marked as an output›
    C' ∈ set (class_def.interfaces cl)
  ⟧ ⟹ is_subtype1 P C C'"
```

The problem is that there are multiple possible values for `C'` and that it cannot be marked as an output.

Intuitively, I think this should not be a problem for the code generator, as the generated code could just iterate over all the interfaces of a class. However, I don't know if this can be expressed in Isabelle/HOL.

Thus, the question is: Is there a way to generate code for `is_subtype1` with mode `i ⇒ i ⇒ o ⇒ bool`?

Comment: What are the theory imports? The predicate compiler by default doesn't handle `_ ∈ set _`, but it should if you import `HOL-Library.Predicate_Compile_Alternative_Defs`. I cannot test this though as the above code is missing the definitions for `Program`, `get_class`, etc.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I did some copy/paste errors. The definition of `is_subtype1` now also uses `lookup_class` etc like the first snippet. I do not think it's because of `_ ∈ set _` because code generation works for the mode `i ⇒ i ⇒ i ⇒ bool` (I just tried `HOL-Library.Predicate_Compile_Alternative_Defs` but it does not seem to make a difference). I also tried replacing `_ ∈ set _` with a function `contains :: 'a ⇒ 'a list ⇒ bool`, but this also didn't work.

Comment: You can use `List.member _ _` instead of `_ ∈ set _`.

Comment: Yes, thank you! Totally overlooked `List.member`, now it's working! (If you post an answer I will accept it)

Comment: Also, since something like `values "{c. is_subtype <program> <class> c}"` will loop forever, you might need to add alternative introduction rules for `rtranclp` along the lines of Section 4.2 from _Code generation from Isabelle/HOL_ theories in the Isabelle documentation.

Comment: I think this should be covered by "HOL-Library.Transitive_Closure_Table", which is really convenient. At least so far everything seems to terminate fine.

Comment: That's correct: Importing `HOL-Library.Transitive_Closure_Table` avoids the need to add such alternative introduction rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve your problem by importing `HOL-Library.Predicate_Compile_Alternative_Defs` and then using `List.member _ _` instead of `_ ∈ set _`.

Comment: BTW, I voted up @Andreas Lochbihler's comment for pointing out the use of `HOL-Library.Predicate_Compile_Alternative_Defs `.